# jquery ajax call always goes to error part but data returned is ok

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, json

Here is my problem :

i try to get the content from a .php file with an ajax query...
the datatype is set on json,
and i give it back from my php file this way : echo json_encode($myData);
the ajax query always goes into "error" and gives me this :

```
STRINGIFY : {"readyState":4,"responseText":"\"SESSION?1\"\"<legend class=\\\"mainLegend\\\">Informations<\\/legend>CON OKUSER = 1\"","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}
```

here is the code... can't find where i am wrong...

JS :

```
//I am already into an AJAX query, so, 
//it succeeds on the first one, but the second     
//one fails
...
success : function(response){
    $.fancybox.close();
    $("#mainField").empty();
    alert('okay');
    //THIS IS WHERE IT FAILS !
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : './php/utils/update.php',
        data : {'id':"test"},
        dataType : 'json',
        error : function(txt){
            alert("ERROR");
            alert("RESPONSE : "+txt);
            alert("STRINGIFY : "+JSON.stringify(txt);
            alert("RESPONSETXT : "+txt.responseText;
        },
        success : function(txt){
            $("#mainField").html(txt);
        }
    });
}
...
```

PHP FILE (update.php) :

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include '../functions.php';
    $text = '<legend class="mainLegend">Informations</legend>';
    $user = $_SESSION['user'];
    $db = connectToDb('test');
    if($db){
        $text .= "CONN OK";
    }else{
        $text .= "CONN FALSE";
    }
    $text .= "USER = ".$user;
    echo json_encode("SESSION?".$_SESSION['user']);
    echo json_encode($text);
?>
```

Thanxx for help ! :)

Comment: What does `alert(txt.status);` say?

Answer (score 1):

```
echo json_encode("SESSION?".$_SESSION['user']);
echo json_encode($text);
```

You have two, sequential JSON texts in your response. This is not *a* valid JSON text, so jQuery fails to parse the response as JSON (you have `dataType: "json"` so it ignores your (default) `text/html` content-type) and errors.

You probably want something like:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo json_encode(Array( session => "SESSION?".$_SESSION['user'], text => $text));
```